# Is the seed of the mersenne_twister_engine instance invariant?

Tags: c++, random, c++17, random-seed

Short question I couldn't find an answer to: I have two instances `g1` and `g2` of `std::mt19937`. If I `seed` `g1` and `g2` with a common `int x`, is it guaranteed that the sequence of samples generated by `g1` is the same as the sequence of samples generated by `g2` (assuming the same distributions are used, of course)? Or is this an "instance seed", i.e. is it only guaranteed that I may reproduce the sequence generated by the particular instance `g1` if I reseed it later to `x` again?

Comment: @Evg What precisely do you mean? Say `std::uniform_real_distribution<> d1` and `std::normal_distribution<> d2`. You mean I shouldn't call `d1(g1)` and `d2(g1)`, i.e. better use another generator for `d2`?

Comment: I mean that `g1()` and `g2()` will produce the same sequences that are independent of the standard library implementation.

Comment: @Evg Didn't you wrote something about distributions?

Comment: I did, but deleted it because the dupe explains it. Both, `mt19937` and `uniform_real_distribution` generate random numbers. For generators you have such a guarantee, but for distributions you don't. Given that `g()` generates the same sequence for the same seed, `uniform_real_distribution` should also generate the same sequence for each particular library implementation. But it seems that this property is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @Evg Maybe I've got a major misunderstanding, but doesn't `uniform_real_distribution` generated the samples based on the based generator? So, if we have to different `uniform_real_distribution d_1,d_2` and `g1, g2` have the same seed, the sequence produced by `d1(g_1)` and `d2(g_2)` should be identical, shouldn't they?

Comment: That's correct. I don't see a way how they could not be identical in practice. The standard [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.req.dist#3.8) that `D()` "creates a distribution whose behavior is indistinguishable from that of any other newly default-constructed distribution of type `D`." But what is "behavior"? Whether this condition strongly implies that `d1(g1)` and `d2(g2)` have to generate same sequences, I can't tell.